# How do you add a button to the Eclipse Project Explorer toolbar?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want a toggle button added to the Project Explorer toolbar - the one that contains "Collapse All" and "Link with Editor".

It seems to possibly involve adding an extension point for somewhere around `org.eclipse.ui.navigator` but I can't find anything that hints at how to do it.

I've tried mimicking how the "Hello World Command" wizard adds a toolbar, with a locationURI of `toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.navigator?after=additions` but that neither works nor gives an error.

I can't find anything useful via search engines.

Plugin needs to work with Indigo (other versions would be a bonus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the view ID is org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer

This worked for me (I'm building on top of Eclipse 3.8):

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
     <menuContribution
           allPopups="false"
           locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer">
        <separator
              name="my.separator"
              visible="true">
        </separator>
        <command
              commandId="com.my.command.id"
              style="push">
        </command>
     </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, this works. :) I'd tried with the .ProjectExplorer bit but not with command as a direct child.

Comment: Worth mentioning that menucontribution>command works but menucontribution>toolbar>command wont.